# Could I switch a 1/4W resistor with a 1/2W resistor?

Tags: resistors, component-selection, circuit-protection

I have a Fender/Sunn SX4150 mixer and it has two resistors blown out and missing, I didn't remove them. I asked another question regarding the schematics that called for a 22 Ohm cc, which I got my answer for but the answeree also noted that instead of a 1/4W I should just make it a 1/2W. Could I do this with little to no consequences, and if so, could I just replace the 1/4's with 1/2's? What would happen if I did such a feat?

Comment: Greater wattage for resistor is good. How much power a resistor could handle is determined by wattage. If the dimension is fitted, you can always replace any resistor with greater wattage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough space you can easily replace them with 1/2W. 1/4W is less than 1/2W. The device will work properly. 1/2W or 1/4W means how much power the resistor can dissipate.